# How do I get the size of objects in a bucket based on storage class

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I have a bucket with objects in standard,IA and Glacier. Is there a way I can get the size of total objects in each storage type? Right now I generate a report every day with total size of the bucket and amount of data added the previous data. I would like to further split it based on the storage class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Inventory** option under **Management** tab to generate detailed inventory of current/all version of objects with details such as Size, Storage Class, replication and expiration status etc.
[Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofOUF.png)

Comment: Thanks Praveen. I am looking to get this info from aws cli or shell script